# Waiting for a file until it is downloaded using C#

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I'm using C# to download different files via url and run them afterwards from a physical filepath in the system, however I need to wait for the file until it is completely written and only then run it. The reason is that some files would need more time than others to be saved and I can't really use Thread.Sleep() for this purpose.

I tried this code but it is not that flexible for some reason, as I can't really tell how many tries or how much time it should be until the file is saved. This depends always on the internet connection as well as on the file size.

```
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   var downloadTask = client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), filepath);
   var checkFile = Task.Run(async () => await downloadTask);
   WaitForFile(filepath, FileMode.CreateNew);
```

—

```
    FileStream WaitForFile(string fullPath, FileMode mode)
    {
        for (int numTries = 0; numTries < 15; numTries++)
        {
            FileStream fs = null;
                try
                {
                    fs = new FileStream(fullPath, mode);
                    return fs;
                }

                catch (IOException)
                {
                    if (fs != null)
                    {
                        fs.Dispose();
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Is there a way to keep waiting until the File.Length > 0?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you download a file?

Comment: Show the relevant code where you download the file. You can wait there instead of monitoring the file system.

Comment: thank you. i added that to the post!

Comment: Is there some reason you just don't do `var checkFile = await downloadTask;`? You mention downloading multiple files, can you add a bit more code so the overall picture is clearer?

Comment: no they are separate single files!

Comment: Note that using (and awating) `DownloadFileTaskAsync`, you can still subscribe to the `DownloadProgressChanged` and `DownloadFileCompleted` events: these are not available to just the `DownloadFileAsync` method (in case you need to report progress or perform a predefined action when the download completes).

Answer (score 2):

You're not awaiting for the file to complete download. Or better said, you're awaiting, in a different thread, and then throwing that result away. Just wait in the very same method and you no longer need a separate way to know when the file is downloaded

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), filepath);
```

Comment: I didn't answer with this, and preferred to comment instead, because the surrounding code might be for downloading all files in parallel, and this effectively blocks parallelization :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileSystemWatcher to get an event when file changes its size or a new file appear https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged?view=netcore-3.1

But you can't really tell if the file is fully downloaded this way unless you know its size.

You should just change the code that downloads the file so that it notifies when the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all you have to do:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
 await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), filepath);
 // code continues when the file finishes downloading
```